# Cannot Export Shape Key Animations with FBX in Blender

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

Hello Blender Community,

I am encountering an issue where I am unable to export shape key animations along with my FBX file from Blender. Although I initially had both a walking animation and facial expressions for my character "Lois Body.001", I have since simplified the project to focus solely on the shape key animations for the facial expressions.

Despite the shape keys being properly keyframed within Blender, these animations are not being included in the exported FBX file. Here's what I'm observing:

The character mesh has several shape keys intended for facial expressions.
The Dope Sheet confirms the presence of keyframes for these shape keys, indicating they are animated.
The Blender outliner shows these shape keys under the mesh data for "Lois Body.001".
No specific 'Shape Animations' option is visible in the FBX export dialogue to ensure these are included.
After exporting, the FBX file lacks the shape key animations when I attempt to import it into other software or back into Blender.
Steps I've taken:

I've ensured the 'Mesh' is selected under 'Object Types' during export.
I've checked 'Bake Animation' in the FBX export dialogue.
I've looked for any explicit 'Shape Key' export settings but found none.
Here is a brief outline of the current setup in Blender:

[image]
Can anyone provide guidance on the proper export settings or procedures to ensure that my shape key animations are exported within the FBX file?

My Blender version: 3.6
Target Software for FBX Import: unreal engine 5.3

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: i think there is something wrong with blender or my computer because when i make a new file in blender 4.1 with just a cube and used shape keys make a basic animation and it still wont export